# Maximum value of an auto type

Tags: visual-c++

I was working with both auto variables and template variables.

```
    auto minDist = some template value T(double/int usually);

    minDist = max value for minDist;
    if (T + 100 < minDist)
        etc. etc.
```

I was wondering if there was a clean way to set minDist to its maximum value. Or should I leave minDist as an int and the if would still run fine?

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for

```
std::numeric_limits<decltype(minDist)>::max()
```

---

The way you plan to use this value doesn't make much sense though. E.g. if `T` is of a signed  integral type, either `T + 100` is well-defined and is less than or equal to the largest value of `decltype(T)`, or else `T + 100` overflows and the program exhibits undefined behavior.

For unsigned integral type, any value is less than or equal to the max value, including `T + 100` (the overflow for such types is well-defined and wraps around).

For a `double`, I expect `T + 100 == T` for a `T` that's close enough to a largest representable `double` value; 100 is well outside the representable precision for such a large number.